# Java poker game creating a head checker

Tags: java

I've created a java poker program and I've got is so that I can check to see if if the player or dealer has a pair and if they do the winner get the pot into their account balance. I now want to get it so that if a player has a straight of royal flush the program will read it and put the winnings into the winners account. I want to use a loop. this is my code so far

```
private int flush(List<PokerCard> hand)
{
    List<PokerCard> handToSort = new ArrayList<PokerCard>();
    Collections.copy(handToSort, hand);
    Collections.sort(handToSort, new CardComparator());
    {
        List<PokerCard> deck = new ArrayList<PokerCard> ();
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i ++)
        {
            for (int j = 8; j < 13; j ++)
            {
                System.out.println("You have a Royal Flush 10 through Ace!!");
                return flush;
            }
            else (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
            {
                System.out.println("You have a straigth 2 through 6!!");
                return flush;
            }
            else (int j = 1; j < 7; j++)
            {
                System.out.println("You have a straigth 3 through 7!!");
                return flush;
            }
            else (int j = 2; j < 8; j ++)
            {
                System.out.println("You have a straigth 4 through 8!!");
                return flush;
            }
            else (int j = 3; j < 9; j++)
            {
                System.out.println("You have a straigth 5 through 9!!");
                return flush;
            }
            else (int j = 4; j < 10; j++)
            {
                System.out.println("You have a straigth 6 through 10!!");
                return flush;
            }
            else (int j = 5; j < 11; j++)
            {
                System.out.println("You have a straigth 7 through Jack!!");
                return flush;
            }
            else (int j =6; j < 12; j++)
            {
                System.out.println("You have a straigth 8 through Queen!!");
                return flush;
            }
            else (int j = 7; j < 13; j ++)
            {
                System.out.println("You have a straigth 9 through King!!");
                return flush;
            }
```

it is showing as an error for this code but I can't see what's wrong. I'm fairly new to coding and set myself a challenge but my have bitten off more than I can chew

Comment: You're mixing up a for loop, and an if-else statement, creating some sort of unholy `for-else` construct. Javac doesn't like that. I recommend a good dose of the basic tutorials (as well as an exorcism).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for` statements have no `else` component. So this...

```
        for (int j = 8; j < 13; j ++)
        {
            System.out.println("You have a Royal Flush 10 through Ace!!");
            return flush;
        }
        else (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
        {
            System.out.println("You have a straigth 2 through 6!!");
            return flush;
        }
```

Would become this...

```
        for (int j = 8; j < 13; j ++)
        {
            System.out.println("You have a Royal Flush 10 through Ace!!");
            return flush;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
        {
            System.out.println("You have a straight 2 through 6!!");
            return flush;
        }
```

It looks like you might want to return a boolean instead of an integer, which would change the signature of the function to this...

```
private boolean flush(List<PokerCard> hand)

        for (int j = 8; j < 13; j ++)
        {
            System.out.println("You have a Royal Flush 10 through Ace!!");
            return true;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
        {
            System.out.println("You have a straight 2 through 6!!");
            return true;
        }
```

At the very end of all of your checks, you'd want to add a `return false`. There are other alternatives to a boolean here, but seems best suited to the question, "is this hand a flush?"

The function also has a lot of redundant code that you could eliminate and still do the same work. Once you get it working, you should put some effort into that.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that are wrong with your program.

First, you are using both for loops and if-else statements incorrectly. What you probably intended to write would look more like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    if(handToSort.get(i).value >= 8 || handToSort.get(i).value <=13)
    {
        System.out.println("You have a Royal Flush 10 through Ace!!");
    }
}
```

The second problem is that your function returns an integer but it looks like you are trying to return a string when you write

```
return flush;
```

You also aren't checking to see what the card's suite is. That is a requirement for checking to see whether or not you have a flush or not.